# How to use a reference to a pointer in a C++ function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to implement a simple linked list. I need an `insert` function that takes a value and a node to insert after, so I have this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node node;
struct node {
  int data;
  node * next = NULL;
};

void insert(node *& head, int value, node *& insert_after_me) {
  node n; n.data = value;
  node * new_node = &n;

  if (insert_after_me == NULL) {
    insert_after_me = new_node;
    cout << "after assign insert: " << insert_after_me->data << endl;

    head = new_node;
    cout << "after assign head: " << head->data << endl;
  }
}

int main () {
  node * head = NULL;
  node * new_node = NULL;

  insert(head, 1, new_node);
  cout << head->data << endl;
  cout << new_node->data << endl;

  cout << head << endl;
  cout << new_node << endl;
}
```

This is obviously an imcomplete implementation, but when I run it I get the following as output:

```
after assign insert: 1
after assign head: 1
1
1924530936
0x7fff56177928
0x7fff56177928
```

This tells me in `main`, `head` and `new_node` are pointing to the same thing, yet they have different values stored in `data`. Why?

Note: Though it seems to me a nonsensical implementation to make insert take a node to insert after and then change that node, that's a requirement of the project. I can't change *how* insert is called.

Comment: "*How to use a reference to a pointer in a C++ function?*" Like this: `void foo(bar*& p) { p++; }`

Comment: What will happen, if `insert_after_me` is not null ?

Comment: @Shravan40 not a whole lot, but the looks of it. I'm still gathering thoughts to express what course could lead someone to using pointers by reference, but not-yet-cover object lifetime (`node n` in `insert`).

Comment: You're right, fiddling with this some more and not creating `node n` like that seems to work. I think I'd have to do something like `head = new node()` to keep a reference to it alive. That seems to work, anyway. Post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Your object `node n` is destructed after the function `void insert (...)` exits and `main` variables are left with dangling pointer!! Instead allocate as `node *new_node = new node; new_node->data = value` and it should fix what appears to be erroneous output. As others have opined, please consider taking *good* programming courses.